# Namespaces for classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The idea is simple: to create a hierarchy of classes in `/app/` directory and, of course, use them. So I created `/namespace` directory and here what I have (don't pay attension at this name please, it's just for convenience):

```
#app/namespace/base.rb
module Namespace
  class Base
    def initialize item
      puts 'Namespace Base'
    end
  end
end


#app/namespace/class1.rb
class Namespace::Class1 < Namespace::Base
  def initialize item
    puts 'Namespace Class1'
  end
end

#app/namespace/class2.rb
class Namespace::Class2 < Namespace::Base
  def initialize item
    puts 'Namespace Class2'
  end
end

#somewhere in a controller
a = Namespace::Class1.new
```

and the error I have is `initialize: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)` caused at `Class1` constructor.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this marked as Ruby on Rails, so this will be a rails specific answer -
if this is not relevant to you, please edit your question and take out rails ;)

Make sure to disambiguate a rails 'namespace'.

In your 'routes.rb', to have a '/namespace' directory, you can actually use the rails 'namespace' method to create this for you.

```
namespace :namespace do
  get 'something' => 'some#action'
  put 'something' => 'some#otheraction'
end
```

which will create a rails route to use `/namespace/something`

Answer (score 3):

This

```
a = Namespace::Class1.new
```

attempts to create a *new* instance of `Class1`, you are currently passing it no arguments. If you take a look at `Class1`s constructor, it requires an *item* argument. Your error stems from not passing in the argument.

```
#app/namespace/class1.rb
class Namespace::Class1 < Namespace::Base
  def initialize item   
    puts 'Namespace Class1'
  end
end
```

Solutions:

1. Remove the `item` parameter from the `Class1` constructor(it doesn't appear to be used anyway)
2. Pass in a value for `item` when you construct `Class1` objects
3. Add a default value for `item` in the constructor

The first one seems ideal since you *never* use `item` in any of your classes.

Comment: o my God, I didn't pay attention to it.

Comment: why doesn't this work  for the Base class -- `class Base::Namespace ... end` --> `uninitialized constant Base (NameError)`?

Comment: I think you mean `Namespace::Base` right ?

Comment: yes............ -- instead of saying "module Namespace class Base " I want to say "class Namespace::Base"

Comment: `class Namespace::Base` means that Base is a class *inside* of the `Namespace` Module

Comment: So to do `class Namespace::Base
  def initialize item
    puts 'Namespace Base'
  end
end
` will always be wrong?

Comment: Why do you think you need `item` there ?

Comment: The question is about presence of item but about the structure of a namespace.

Comment: Your question appears to be about why you receive a certain error when initializing a Class1 object.

Comment: no, my main man, get out of town.

Answer (score 0):

You can also define class constructors using `Struct`:

```
class Base < Struct.new(item)
end

> Base.new.item
 => nil
> Base.new(:car).item
 => :car
```

- Easier to scan
- Less code
- Enforces simplicity
- Free setter and getter
- More flexibility (won't raise if `item` is not provided, instead set to `nil`)